# Дефис: «процедурно сгенерированный» или «процедурно-сгенерированный»?

Tags: орфография

Нужен ли дефис во фразе «процедурно(-)сгенерированный» (от термина «процедурная генерация»)? Если что, это перевод английского "procedurally generated".

Comment: Вам [сюда](https://rus.stackexchange.com/). Если кратко, то [да](http://language.edu.ru/catalog.asp?cat_ob_no=21175&ob_no=21343).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не нужен. Это словосочетание из наречия и причастия.Розенталь:

> Различаются сложные прилагательные, образующие одно слово (со слитным или дефисным написанием, см. выше), и словосочетания, состоящие из наречия на -о (-е) и прилагательного или причастия (с раздельным написанием); к наречию, играющему роль отдельного члена предложения, можно поставить соответствующий вопрос.

Ср.:
морально-этические проблемы – морально устойчивый человек (в каком отношении устойчивый?);
общественно-исторические законы – общественно опасные элементы (опасные для кого?)
Розенталь Справочник по русскому языку.   гл1Х§43 п14.

Процедурно сгенерированный  (сгенерированный как?каким образом?)

For everybody to understand. 
No, you shouldn't use a hyphen because it's a participle with an adverb. Rosental says we should distinguish between compound adjectives (hyphenated or not) and such phrases. When an adverb is a separate sentence element, you can ask a question

Процедурно сгенерированный (сгенерированный как?каким образом?)Generated in what way?How?

Comment: The answer is correct, but _сгенерированный_ is a participle not an adjective. (Все правильно, только это не прилагательное, а причастие.)